# Bluemix Blockchain Marbles app is hanging

Tags: ibm-cloud, sample, blockchain

I've gone through the steps to deploy the marbles app on Bluemix and it's running but when I go to 'create' it the 'colour' pull down doesn't populate, the 'create' button doesn't do anything and there is a 'loading...' message in the top right corner. I've tried looking at the logs but can't spot anything. A blockchain entry keeps appearing and disappearing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the client side console logs in your browser and look for clues. Right click the page, inspect, click on the console tab. Should be something helpful in there.

Details debugging can be found here:
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/i_lost_my_marbles.md

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by reinstalling it on a US instance instead of the UK one. Maybe its something to do with time zones as it was the display of the time that wasn't working even though it's UTC. I wasn't getting anywhere with devops services in the UK either.